# Meteor + Polymer - core-submenu throws 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.items.length')' in Safari

Tags: javascript, meteor, safari, polymer, meteor-blaze

I am building a menu for my Meteor + Polymer project.  I am using a 'core-submenu' that uses the title and id of each element in a collection.

This works perfectly in Chrome (Mac) but when the menu is clicked in Safari, I get :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.items.length')
```

My Router Code looks like this :

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'layout',
waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('debates'); },
data: function() {
return {debates : Debates.find().fetch()}
}
});
```

My Template :

```
<core-submenu label="Debates ({{no}})" icon="menu" class="">
  {{#each debates}}
  <core-submenu label="{{title}}" icon="arrow-forward" class="">
    <core-item label="Link" icon='link' horizontal="" center="" layout=""><a href="/{{_id}}" ></a></core-item>
    <core-item label="Analyse" icon="trending-up" horizontal="" center="" layout=""><a href="/analysis/{{_id}}"></a></core-item>
    <core-item label="Edit" icon="create" horizontal="" center="" layout=""><a href="/edit/{{_id}}"></a></core-item>
    <core-item label="Clear Data" icon="remove-circle-outline" horizontal="" center="" layout=""><a href="/clear/{{_id}}"></a></core-item>
    <core-item label="Delete Debate" icon="delete" horizontal="" center="" layout=""><a href="/del/{{_id}}"></a></core-item>
  </core-submenu>
{{/each}}
</core-submenu>
```

This can be seen online : http://dya.meteor.com/

I have been scratching my head over this for a long while, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried waiting for the polymer ready event?

```
window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
  //Code Here
});
```

Most issues surrounding undefined polymer objects can be resolved by the polymer-ready event.

Comment: Hi Flying Emu, thanks for the suggestion.  So I tried what you said, and set a session variable in the 'polymer-ready' event, this was returned in the Template Helper.  Again this worked fine in Chrome, but failed in Safari (same error).

Comment: Wait, so the error appears once you click on the menu in Safari?

Comment: Yes, if I look at the console in Safari, as I click on the menu, the error shows.